# Hex Color code not working correctly when using fonts in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason the colors in my Pygame program does not work correctly on fonts and I mean by the color when using hexadecimals compared to tuples/lists

Here's one

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont("None", 32)
text = font.render("Hello World!", True, 0xFFFFFF) # 0xFFFFFF is equivalent to (255, 255, 255)
screen.blit(text, (0, 0))
```

In this image, white in hexadecimal somehow looks cyan(ish)

[image: A Cyan(ish) text saying "Hello World!"]

Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: When you pass an integer into most pygame field that expects colors, it interprets the integer as a color mapped onto the pixelformat of the surface involved. So this will could lead to different results with different surfaces or between different machines. If you insist on hex, passing it as a string will parse correctly inside pygame.

Answer (score 1):

## A: Yes!

There are two fixes and they are easy.

### Fix A : Extra Bytes

By bit-shifting 8 times to the left.

Lets say we have this color in hex: **0xFFFFFF**, its white if displayed.

```py
color = 0xFFFFFF # X | Wrong
```

when using `pygame.font.Font.render()` ; using the color in hexadecimal makes it have an extra few bytes that it will use as what I think the alpha or opacity but because it doesn't work (I think you need to enable something to use it.) we can just add an additional `00` to the end of the data

Like this

```py
color = 0xFFFFFF00 # O | Correct
```

Or if you wanna show off to your friends you can use bitwise operators (Not Recommended)

```py
color = 0xFFFFFF << 8 # ? | Correct but NOT RECOMMENDED
```

### Fix B : Using Tuples/Lists

This is extremely easy and you probably had mentioned it in your question

> For some reason the colors in my PyGame program does not work correctly on fonts and I mean by the color when using hexadecimals **compared to tuples/lists**

Instead of doing

```py
text = font.render("Hello World!", True, 0xFFFFFF) # X | Wrong
```

We can just go the easy way and do

```py
text = font.render("Hello World!", True, (255, 255, 255)) # O | Correct
```

With that all said, here is the comparison:

[image: White Text Saying "Hello World!"] (Before)

[image: A Cyan(ish) text saying "Hello World!"] (After)